# Selenium missing chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

Through selenium test we have to invoke the chrome webdriver as an executable file and then call a method on it:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.rahulshettyacademy.com/")
```

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver' has no attribute 'chrome'
```

Comment: did you install the actual [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)? it's not enough to just install selenium

Comment: Can you add the import statement to the question? You can use "from selenium.webdriver import Chrome" to import the Chrome driver class. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py

Answer (score 0):

First check that `chromedriver` is installed:

```
# Run in terminal, this should start a chromedriver instance
chromedriver
```

> [Chromedriver downloads](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Then try without specifying the `executable_path`, as `chromedriver` should be in your `PATH` variable

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```